# Youtube Player Glitch on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: google-chrome, video, flash, youtube

I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` with latest version of Chrome (70.0.3538.67). Whenever I open a YouTube video for the first time, this YouTube player will act weird like shown in picture below. It zoom in the player and control button got hidden a bit. Already turn off all the extensions, didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem here, but with Ubuntu 18.10. I noticed that it happens when the dock is placed at the left or right of the screen. Changed to bottom and worked.